# blank Recyclerview inside Fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am using fragment and recyclerview together. I also have database and I want to query results coming from the database and display the results inside the activity.

However every time I try to run the application and switch to the part to get and view the results, I don't seem to get anything. No results at all just blank. I don't know why it's not showing up.

This is my full code

Sample class

```
public class Sample extends Fragment {
    private View rootView;

    public Sample() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        rootView = inflater.inflate(sample, container, false);

        RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_sample);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        DatabaseHandler db= new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
        List<SampleModel> list = db.getResults();

        SampleAdapter sampleAdapter = new SampleAdapter(list);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(sampleAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Adapter Class

```
public class SampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <SampleAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<SampleModel> list;
    private Context mContext;

    public SampleAdapter (List<SampleModel> list) {
        list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public SampleAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.sample_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SampleAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        SampleModel sample = list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        holder.title.setText(sample.getTitle())
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (list != null? list.size():0);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView title;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
    }
}
```

XML

sample.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <include layout="@layout/sample_recyclerview" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

sample_recyclerview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_sample"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

sample_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#808080">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `SampleAdapter` change

```
list = list;
```

to

```
this.list = list;
```

Comment: Are you really sure that your `List<SampleModel> list = db.getResults();` is not empty?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Adapter` constructor is wrong. You are not passing the `dataSource` to your adapter. Change it to

```
 public SampleAdapter (List<SampleModel> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
```

Furthermore you have to notify the adapter that you changed your `dataSource`. You do that by calling the method `notifyDataSetChanged`

```
SampleAdapter sampleAdapter = new SampleAdapter(list);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(sampleAdapter);
sampleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score -1):

RecyclerViews will return nothing if the size is not rightly returned(e.g using : return 0;)
 change your code from :
  public int getItemCount() {
        return (list != null? list.size():0);
     To:

```
 public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
```